# deleting xml file having errors after parsing in java

Tags: java, xml

I am trying to delete a xml file having errors after parsing it. parsing process throws an Exception. Problem occurs only under windows os. Under Linux, deletion works correctly.
This is the code i used,

```
 try{
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

    Document doc = (Document) db.parse(file);
     } catch(Exception e){
    file.delete();
 }
```

Comment: Please provide the stacktrace : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Does `file.delete()` throws an exception? Is the path to the file correct?

The problem with your code is that it doesn't make any difference if there is a parsing problem (`SAXException`) or if the file you give to your `DocumentBuilder` is incorrect (`IOException`).

Comment: file.delete() does not throws exception. Exception occurs while parsing. Filepath is also correct. Problem occurs only in windows os. I tried by adding seperate catch blocks also.

Comment: I'd suppose that Windows considers that the file you were trying to parse is still in use and so the file stays locked, but I may be wrong. I don't know if the parse method closes the stream when throwing an exception.

Edit : Instead of giving a file to the DocumentBuilder, try to open a FIleInputStream before, pass it in parameter and explicitly close it before deleting the file.

Comment: i debugged the file. delete statement is executing. but file does not deleted.